# How to check if an element has duplicated attributes with cheerio js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I'm parsing HTML files with cheerio (to later test with Mocha), and the HTML elements in these files can have lots of attributes, I want to check if the attribute is repeated within the same element:

example partial file that has an element with repeated "class" attribute:

```
<div class="logo-center" data-something-very-long="something long" ... class="logo" data-more-stuff>
```

Here is the code that loads the file:

```
var fileContents = fs.readFileSync(file, "utf8");
var $ = cheerio.load(fileContents);
```

Note: it doesn't have to be a class attribute, it could be any other attribute that repeats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the element under test again. For that to work, you need to dive a bit into the raw DOM object produced by cheerio/htmlparser2. It uses properties that are documented for [domhandler](https://github.com/fb55/DomHandler), but not for cheerio, so some care with the versions might be needed. I have tested with

```
└─┬ cheerio@1.0.0-rc.1 
  ├─┬ htmlparser2@3.9.2 
  │ ├── domhandler@2.4.1
```

I have formulated this ES6-style, but you could do the same as easily with older, more conventional constructs.

The RegExp may need some refining, though, depending on your expectations on the files you are testing.

```
const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(file, "utf8");
const $ = cheerio.load(fileContents, {
  useHtmlParser2: true,
  withStartIndices: true,
  withEndIndices: true
});

function getDuplicateAttributes ($elem) {
    const dom = $elem.get(0);

    // identify tag text position in string
    const start = dom.startIndex;
    const end = dom.children.length ? dom.children[0].startIndex : dom.endIndex + 1;
    // extract
    const html = fileContents.slice(start, end);

    // generator function loops through all attribute matches on the html string
    function* multivals (attr) {
        const re = new RegExp(`\\s${attr}="(.*?)"`, 'g');
        let match;
        while((match = re.exec(html)) !== null) {
            // yield each property value found for the attr name
            yield match[1];
        }
    }

    // the DOM will contain all attribute names once
    const doubleAttributeList = Object.keys(dom.attribs)
       // compound attribute names with all found values
      .map((attr) => {
           const matchIterator = multivals(attr);
           return [attr, Array.from(matchIterator)];
      })
      // filter for doubles
      .filter((entry) => entry[1].length > 1);

    return new Map(doubleAttributeList);
}
```

You haven't stated what you want to do once you have found doubles, so they are just returned.

Comment: I did try it, but it doesn't work as expected because cheerio parses the HTML beforehand, removing unneeded attributes, e.g. `<div class="my-class" class="my-other-class" data-something="something" data-something-else></div>` **to** `<div class="my-class" data-something="something" data-something-else=""></div>`

Comment: I am sorry, there were some really dumb errors in the code, the most important one the greedy quantifier for the RegEx. It must be written as `new RegExp('\\sclass="(.*?)"', 'g')`.

Comment: Don't worry about the bugs, I don't copy paste, I got your idea, rebuilt it from scratch and the code worked but the solution didn't. I ended up having to check the file itself for opening tags, and compare it with what cheerio gave me (less straightforward and more expensive but works).

Comment: I just saw your edition, I'll try it one more time and get back to you

Comment: I tested this, it works as expected! The solution relied on using `withStartIndices` and `withEndIndices`, cheers! I will do some edits to the code to remove unneeded ES6 syntax (make it simpler and cleaner for anyone to read). :+1:

Comment: My edit got rejected because it refactored the code, I'll add it as a separate answer for other people to see, thanks so much @ccprog

Answer (score 0):

@ccprog answer worked, here is a small ES5 refactor:

```
var file = 'some file';
var fileContents = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8');
var $ = cheerio.load(fileContents, {
  useHtmlParser2: true,
  withStartIndices: true,
  withEndIndices: true
});

function getDuplicateAttributes ($elem) {
  var dom = $elem.get(0);

  // identify tag text position in fileContents
  var start = dom.startIndex;
  var end = dom.children.length ? dom.children[0].startIndex : dom.endIndex + 1;

  // extract
  var html = fileContents.slice(start, end);

  // the DOM will contain all attribute names once
  return Object.keys(dom.attribs)
    // compound attribute names with all found values
    .map(function (attr) {
      // modify regexp to capture values if needed
      var regexp = new RegExp('\\s' + attr + '[\\s>=]', 'g');
      return html.match(regexp).length > 1 ? attr : null;
    })
    // filter for doubles
    .filter(function (attr) {  
      return attr !== null;
    });
}

var duplicatedAttrs = getDuplicateAttributes($(".some-elem"));
```

The code:

- removes generator
- ES6 to ES5
- improve RegExp
- use string.match() instead of regexp.exec().

Comment: The downside to this RegExp is that you don't learn which values got entered for the doubled attributes. (You are obviously aware of that - just to make a note of it.)

Comment: That is correct, I only needed to know which attributes are repeated within the HTML.